# How to put column before other column SQL

Tags: sql

When using

```
Select * FRom table;
```

i have columns a,b,c
but i want to have view as A,C,B 
Except `Select * from table where a,c,b`;

Is there other how to make this happen ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Select a, c, b
From mytable
```

This is your only option, and in my opinion you should be always selecting columns by name instead of * so that you don't get any surprises when the schema changes (new columns added for example)

Comment: but what if I have 56 columns ? i need just column num 52 before column 51 *- how to make this ? :D

Comment: Agree with @Bassam Mehanni, it is generally better to avoid * in production SQL if you can.  It makes things safer for you if someone changes the schema

Comment: You still have to select them by name :)

Comment: ok now here is a true - i did not ask about * I ask how to put other column C before column B , and not to type all columns becasue i have 56 columns - lot of them :D

Comment: See my answer - it is not possible without dropping and recreating the table

Answer (score 2):

```
select a, c, b from table
```

`*` means that you want to get all fields, in their default order.

Comment: ok i make like you type * but I have copy like 56 columns , so is there other way ?? :D

Comment: What do you need this 56 columns for? To see these on the screen, or to use these somewhere else programmatically? In the latter case, you should reference to the fields by column names, and not to rely on their positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reorder columns in a table once it's created - you can only append to the end.  As mentioned above you can select the order in the query.

Your only other option is to script the table, drop the table and manually update the order in the script.  You'll obviously risk losing data and issues with FKs doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand your question. If you are saying that

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyView
EXCEPT
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable;
```

is failing because the VIEW and the table  have different column ordering then use

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyView
EXCEPT CORRESPONDING
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable;
```

unless your SQL product of choice does not support it in which case you will either have to write all the columns out (recommended) or change the ordinal positions of the columns in one of the tables (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view of that table that puts the columns in the order you want. For Example:

```
CREATE VIEW viewMyView
as  
SELECT
Column5,  
Column1,  
Column2,  
Column3,  
Column6,  
Column7,  
Column8,  
Column4
FROM myTable
```

Then you can do Select * from viewMyView